# How to set target of UIGestureRecognizer to another class in iOS

Tags: ios7, delegates, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to set the selector method of UILongPressGestureRecognizer to another class. I have created an object of the second class and set it to as target by replacing "self". But the selector method is not being called on long press. Do i have to do anything else ??

I have declared like this in .h file

```
delegateViewController *delegateviewcontroller;
```

and set target in .m file

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:delegateviewcontroller  action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
    [gestureRecognizer setMinimumPressDuration:0.2];
    [tv1 addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    [self.view addSubview:tv1];
```

tv1 is UItextview instance.

Comment: Are you creating a separate instance of the second class to set as the delegate, or you are using the instance which is already there? The point here is that both the instance should be same.

Comment: @EmptyStack i have added my code

Comment: Another basic question: Have you allocated * delegateviewcontroller*?

Comment: @EmptyStack nop !!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks alot . . . . Actually I did initialize it first then removed it by mistake. Thanks once again